# 403 Forbidden: nginx is blocking default page

Tags: linux, nginx, plesk

If I go to my website `example.com` I get an 403 Forbidden error from nginx but not on `example.com/index.html` (the indexfile is default). I use `Plesk Onyx 17.0.17` on `CentOS 6.9`. Every other file in my webspace is loading correctly. Only on the clear domain `example.com` it is not working. I have the default nginx configuration.

**https://example.com = 403 Forbidden;
https://example.com/index.html = working**

Comment: What do the logs say? What is your nginx config?

Comment: Is nginx configured to deliver index.html as a default page?

Comment: Error log is empty and the default page is index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I changed from FPM to FastCGI in the PHP-Settings (Plesk).
[Plesk PHP-Settings (Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Mxc.png)